# How to truncate decimal value then compare in Linq.Expressions c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, expression

I have expression helper class that I use for server side filtering for the column names that I check dynamically such as:

```
 public static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> PropertyContains<TItem>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, string value)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem));

        var m = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propertyInfo);
        var c = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
        var mi = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        var body = Expression.Call(m, mi, c);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, param);
    }
```

This one works perfectly fine. I also have another static helper method to compare if the values are equal:

```
 public static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> PropertyEquals<TItem, TValue>(
            PropertyInfo property, TValue value)
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem));
            var xx = Expression.Property(param, property);
            var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, property),
                Expression.Constant(value));
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, param);
        }
```

That as well works perfectly fine.

BUT, for the decimal fields (`Decimal(19,4)` in SQL) the issue I am having is, user only see the 2 digits as decimal place on UI lets say $19.32
So when they enter 19.32 into search field, it does not match with db record as the record in db is actually 19.3224 let say. So mathematically `19.32 != 19.3224` but as I only show 2 decimal places on UI, it does not return the record user looking for.

My problem is, I am not sure how to manipulate db record's value in Expression. Or even using Decimal.Truncate would be sufficient for now (which means it is ok if I ignore the decimal places and only compare the int part)

I tried something like below:

```
 public static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> PropertyEqualMoneyFields<TItem>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, decimal value) 
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem));

            var m = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propertyInfo);
            var c = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(decimal));
            var mi = typeof(decimal).GetMethod("Truncate", new Type[] { typeof(decimal) });
            var body = Expression.Call(m, mi, c);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, param); 
        }
```

and the way I call this as:

```
string filteredColumnNameInDb = "SomeMoneyColumnName"; // coming from ui actually
 PropertyInfo filteredProperty = typeof(SomeDto).GetProperty(filteredColumnNameInDb);
 query = query.Where(ExpressionHelper.PropertyEqualMoneyFields<SomeDto>filteredProperty,decimal.Truncate(decimalValue)));
```

but it throws an exception as `Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.`, and even though there would be no exception, that would not work anyways as I still need to apply `Expression.Equal` at some point to compare if they are equal after the truncate.

If I am totally off the road with this approach, I would love to hear any other way to do this.

Or if this is not clear, that would be very useful if someone can point to "running a sql function on db record before doing any comparison" so maybe I would create some sql function to apply to that record first, then do the `Expression.Equal` comparison.

**PS: I know I can do this easily after ToList() but that is the whole point of the server side filtering as I do NOT want to load the whole dataset!**

Comment: Rather than equality, how about evaluating `field >= 19.32m && field < 19.33m` instead?

Comment: @BenCottrell - even that would work if I can wrap it in Expression. But I dont know how I can do that. Do you have any idea if I can call 2 consecutive methods before returning  Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, param) ? Maybe I can go that direction like: 
 var body = Expression.Call(m, methodOne, c);
then 
 body = Expression.Call(m, methodTwo, c);
then  return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, param);  something like this..